# What framework persistence , openshift + mongodb, jpa

Tags: mongodb, jpa, openshift

I am implementing a project with rest web services and mongodb  , I would be useful to use JPA for database operations . Necessarily I need to use Hibernate ?, it would be optimal with some other lighter framework. The database is small few entities , but many records, if possible also will insert images , if the OpenShift permits. Is best used as framewrork persistence in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question as old as databases. IMHO, there is nothing wrong with writing a few simple [Data Access Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154202/data-access-object-dao-in-java). Stackoverflow may offer a few helpful posts.

[Spring DAO vs Spring ORM vs Spring JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990400/spring-dao-vs-spring-orm-vs-spring-jdbc).

[JPA or JDBC, how are they different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881548/jpa-or-jdbc-how-are-they-different).

[Hibernate or JPA or JDBC or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560500/hibernate-or-jpa-or-jdbc-or).

[JPA vs Spring JdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573975/jpa-vs-spring-jdbctemplate).