# Has Spring an ORM, or just use ORM Frameworks?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I begin with Spring Framework to do the object relation mapping process, but i am not sure about if Spring 4 has an implicit ORM or just use other ORM Frameworks (like Hibernate, iBatis, etc).

Please help me to know. I have found some responses that say that Spring has an ORM and others say the opposite.

Comment: hope this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990400/spring-dao-vs-spring-orm-vs-spring-jdbc) will  help you to get a idea about Spring.

Comment: Thanks Rajith, that information was useful for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

spring does not have its own orm implementation. spring's orm is a layer of abstraction that adds enhancements to the actual orm implementation that you use like hibernate/JDO or JPA.